# Map with automatically expiring elements

Tags: java, collections

I need a `Map` (or any collection) that supports time-to-idle for entries and removes them automatically.

I know there is guava `MapMaker`, but it expires its elements on subsequent read/write operations rather than automatically, by a running thread. Furthermore the expiration capabilities of `MapMaker` are now moved to `CacheBuilder`. The thing is, I don't want a cache - I want expiring elements

Is there something ready-to-use? (it's not hard to implement it myself, but it's better to reuse something)

Comment: Do you need the elements to somehow explicitly "die" (e.g. by calling some method) on time? If you just need to throw away expired elements, checking elements' timestamps at access time should suffice.

Comment: You can have a running thread periodically call Cache.cleanup() to trigger eviction of expired entries. While not immediate, a running thread internally had too many limitations (not J2EE/GAE compatible, suffers from dogpile effect, etc).

Comment: @Ben Manes thanks for the suggestion. However I don't like the Cache interface. First, it forces you to specify value computation. I don't need that. If I return null, it throws a NPE. It's because it always calls getOrCompute, and I need just get - like a simple map. Then, even with catching the NPE, I couldn't make it work (perhaps my fault), but it was always expiring entries, even though they were accessed.

Comment: That's fair. There was debate of whether a null return from a loader was okay (e.g. cache miss). As its easier to loosen a constraint than add it, that may change prior to removing the @Beta status.

You can use cache.asMap() to use a map view of the cache, where a get() will not compute and writes are allowed (in 10.0.1).

Comment: @Ben Manes yup, but that won't refresh the access and items will expire

Answer (score 2):

Maybe: http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/ExpirableCache 
Rather not... it has lots of unresolved imports.

Comment: Its a (old) demonstrative tutorial instead of a provided library, so unresolved imports seemed fair. Its a naive and common approach. I prefer the amortized approach we added to Guava since it avoids stale events piling up.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, you can supply a dummy `CacheLoader` that just throws exceptions, then just don't call `Cache.get` -- only interact with the `asMap` view.  It's not *pretty*, but we're working to support this case better in 11.0.  Make sure you have Guava 10.0.1 if you try this.

And yes, `Cache.cleanUp` is there for you to call as often as you want from whichever threads you want.

Comment: tried that, but the `asMap` view interactions don't refresh the last access.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Mina's ExpiringMap is exactly what you're looking for.

http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/apidocs/org/apache/mina/util/ExpiringMap.html

Comment: Link-only answers aren't the best kind of answers. Could you expand on this by providing a small code sample?

Comment: Check out [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap). It can expire entries based on creation or access time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the `Map` that Hazelcast provides. It also provides distributed capabilites but maybe you are not interested in them. You just need to configure the expiring policy (`time-to-live-seconds` and `max-idle-seconds`) and use the `Map` as if Java's `HashMap` would be.

More info can be found here: [Hazelcast Distributed Map](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/3.1/manual/multi_html/ch02.html#Map)